# Django Logging not outputting to log file on nginx server

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

My Django Logger works fine on my local machine but does not work when I deploy it to the server.

Local: OS X 10.9.5, Python 2.7, Django 1.10.5

AWS Server: Ubuntu, Nginx, Gunicorn, Django

On my local setup I run `python manage.py runserver`, this creates the debug.log file in my root directory. I access the site through localhost:8000 when I boot up the local server via virtual environment and I get these logs on my debug.log.

```
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2908
"GET /projects HTTP/1.1" 200 3461
Inside app views index
```

On my production server I run `python manage.py runserver`, this creates the debug.log file. I restart Nginx server by `sudo service nginx restart`, and I access my webpage and click on the same links as when I was running the local server.

When I `vim debug.log` into the debug.log file, I can not see any of my debug messages after I visit the website and click on the same links in the webpage.

Why is there no logging data being recorded into debug.log on my production environment? What am I missing?

**views.py**

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def index(request):
    logger.debug('Inside app views index')
    return render(request, "first_app/index.html")
```

**local_settings.py** (It shouldn't matter, but I am using local_settings.py in my local machine and production server)

```
#BASE_DIR was already part of django settings.py file when created.
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'debug.log'),
        },
        'null': {
            'class': 'logging.NullHandler',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'apps': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'django.db.backends': {
            'handlers': ['null'],
            'propagate': False,
        },
    },
}
```

**My file routes are**

```
-homepage
  -apps
  -homepage
  -static
  -venv
  manage.py
  homepage.sock
  db.sqlite3
  debug.log
  requirement.txt
```

Comment: Does your nginx user have sufficient permission to write tot he file?

Comment: Can you show your gunicorn command?

Comment: @scott I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for. My debug.log file has "-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu      0 May  1 04:21 debug.log" in the production server when I typed `ls -all`. If this is not what you are looking for please give me a pointer on how to figure out nginx user's permission status to the file.

Comment: @DeanChristianArmada, I'm really new to gunicorn and deployment in general, can you give me a pointer on how to retrieve gunicorn command that you are looking for?

Comment: Like this `gunicorn project.wsgi:application -w 2 -b 0.0.0.0:8000 --log-level info --access-logfile /usr/logs/access.project.log --reload`.. This command will put all the debug logs on the access.project.log

Comment: @DeanChristianArmada, I typed in the command in the AWS command terminal but I am getting `Error: Error: '/usr/logs/access.project.log' isn't writable [IOError(2, 'No such file or directory')]` response.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the requests (GET, POST, etc) logs are intercepted by Nginx and logged to its nginx-access.log, while your INFO, ERROR logs should be in debug.log